# Trying to reassign a property to todays date

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to iterate through array of objects with properties that look like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 123456,
    credentialType: 'oneTimeToken',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    oneTimeToken: 'asdfghjkl'
    disabledOn: 2021-10-10T18:34:36.039Z
  },
  {
    _id: 1234569,
    credentialType: 'email',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '$4567uhji909iuyui'
    createdOn: 2021-10-05T18:34:36.129Z
  }
]
```

I put something like this together:

```
const now = new Date(Date.now())
let credentials = await this.Model.findCredentialsByAid(user.aid, true)
if (!credentials || credentials.length == 0) {
  credentials = await this.Model.findCredentialsByUserId(user._id)
}

credentials.map((credential: any) => {
  if (credential.credentialType === CredentialType.oneTimeToken) {
    if (!(credential.disabledOn < now)) {
      credential.disabledOn = now;
      console.log(credential);
    }
  }
})
```

Instead of getting `credential.disabledOn` reassigned to today's date, I get tomorrow's date.

Comment: If your timezone is GMT-<something> then GMT will appear to be in the future to you, possibly the next day if your local time is less than <something> before midnight. The `Z` at the end of your example timestamps indicate that they're being stored/displayed as GMT/UTC times.

Comment: `new Date(Date.now())` will produce an identical result to `new Date()`. The *Date.now* call is redundant.

Comment: @solarshado, ahh so its doing what it should, but as a result of being stored as GMT, its looking like the next day to me.